# Migrating from SVN to TFS 2017

Tags: svn, tfs, visual-studio-2017, visual-sourcesafe, subversive

Recently we did POC to work java code with TFS by add on tool,now we are planing to migrate java code to TFS 2017.
is any way without third party tool we can migrate SVN to TFS 2017.

Answer (score 4):

Seems you  need to migrate a SVN repository to TFS. If you mean you want to directly use some official SVN or TFS tool to do the migration. I'm afraid there is no such thing for now. You need to use some  other tools. There are two types of version control in TFS: **TFVC** and **GIT**.

For GIT, there are plenty of free tools such as git-svn tool and subgit that will help in migrating Subversion to a Git repository. Once you've created the Git repository locally you can then push it to remote GIT repo hosted by TFS.

For TFVC, one simple option would be to first migrate SVN to GIT, and go from GIT to TFVC using either git-tfs or git-tf.

For detail ways how to do this you could refer below tutorials:

- [Migrate Visual Studio Solution from SVN to TFS](http://blog.nikkipunjabi.com/2015/03/migrating-visual-studio-solution-fro.html)
- [Migrate an SVN repository to TFS](https://www.andyheathershaw.uk/2015/10/migrate-an-svn-repository-to-tfs/)

Besides you could also directly [build the source code in SVN repro](https://java.visualstudio.com/Docs/integrations/subversion) through TFS build system.